# Unit testing Rust Syn crate

Tags: unit-testing, parsing, rust, rust-macros, rust-proc-macros

From the [Syn documentation](https://lib.rs/crates/syn):

> Syn operates on the token representation provided by the `proc-macro2` crate from crates.io rather than using the compiler's built in `proc-macro` crate directly. This enables code using `Syn` to execute outside of the context of a procedural macro, such as in unit tests or `build.rs`

I am trying to enable unit testing for some Syn functions, however I can't get it to work no matter what I have tried. It does not work with the `proc_macro2::TokenStream` type, but it won't work with the `proc_macro::TokenStream` because we are not in a proc-macro context.

[link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=79269a1175339b97213f28f3fa25a06d)

```rust
use quote::quote;
use syn;

fn test() {
    // let stream: syn::export::TokenStream = quote!{fn foo() {};}.into(); // doesn't work
    let stream: proc_macro2::TokenStream = quote!{fn foo() {};}.into(); // doesn't work
    // let item = parse_macro_input!(stream as Item); // doesn't work
    let item = syn::parse(stream).unwrap();

}

fn main() {
    test();
}
```

Any help on how to test syn functions outside of the proc-macro context would be appreciated. I am aware of the [trybuild](https://docs.rs/trybuild/1.0.35/trybuild/) crate, but I would like to be able to unit test the macro's functions first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It does not work with the `proc_macro2::TokenStream` type, but it won't work with the `proc_macro::TokenStream` because we are not in a proc-macro context.

Yes, and that's the whole point! Crates that export procedural macros can't export anything else, but `proc_macro` can only be used in crates that export macros. This is the reason why `proc_macro2` exists in the first place.

You need to use multiple crates in order to write tests for code that uses `syn` and `proc_macro2`:

- Your public crate that declares the macros with `#[proc_macro]` etc., and does very little except convert a `proc_macro::TokenStream` into a `proc_macro2::TokenStream` and vice versa.
- An "internal" crate, containing most of the actual code, which depends on `proc_macro2` but not `proc_macro`. Your tests can go in here.

---

The error you are seeing is because `syn::parse` accepts a `proc_macro::TokenStream`. You can instead use `syn::parse2`, which is identical except that it accepts a `proc_macro2::TokenStream`.

Comment: My code example above does not declare a macro or depend on `proc_macro`. What do my test need to look like to actually use the syn function?

Comment: You can use `parse2` instead of `parse` to accept a `proc_macro2::TokenStream`.

Comment: So it turns out that I don’t need a separate crate to write the tests, so long as I am using `syn::parse2` I can use it in the proc-macro crate.